# Get page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I want to parse some google service page data (adplanner). The problem is that google shows page content using JS and there isn't any api. For example, I have such request url: https://www.google.com/adplanner/planning/site_profile?hl=en#siteDetails?identifier=stackoverflow.com&lp=true

And in received code I can see:

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + AP_gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

I'm receiving page data using `JQuery`:

```
$.get(requestUrl, function(data) {console.log(data);} );
```

`requestUrl` is the url I wrote under this text.

So, any ways to receive **text** data from that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).  It can load the page, run all the javascript, and then you can grab whatever text you want (via the DOM or jQuery) once all the javascript rendering is done.  There are many good examples in the github repo.

Comment: `PhantomJS is a command-line tool` I have to do this in JS code.

Comment: Phantomjs is not JUST a command line tool.  It's a web browser that can be controlled with JS code scripts.  But yes, if you want to get the text and then incorporate it directly into some other web page in a graphical browser in real time, you'll have to seek other methods.  I'm not aware of any other method that's going to easily work though.  You may need to reverse engineer the target page and see exactly which HTTP request generates the text content you are interested in.